# wsgi:alert daemon unable to change working directory of deleted folder

Tags: apache2, services

I've been receiving a lot of errors in the error.log file with something like this:

```
[Sat Oct 07 10:18:06.262085 2017] [wsgi:alert] [pid 18183] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=18183): Unable to change working directory to '/home/iredadmin'.
[Sat Oct 07 10:18:06.263508 2017] [wsgi:alert] [pid 18183] mod_wsgi (pid=18183): Failure to configure the daemon process correctly and process left in unspecified state. Restarting daemon process after delay.
```

Goes on and on.. Now, I recently deleted iredadmin and it's attached files, but as a newbie with working from the terminal, I'm not really sure how to solve this error, my website works as normal, but I would like to solve this error in the logs. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Also I'm not entirely sure what this error means, so if someone could explain it, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Tried to disable wsgi as George suggested, but when I tried to restart apache2 I got the following message.

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I then wrote "journalctl | tail" and got the following:

```
Oct 07 12:29:19 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 07 12:29:19 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Oct 07 12:29:19 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 07 12:29:19 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 07 12:29:37 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=hidden SRC=hidden DST=hidden LEN=434 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=2843 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5072 DPT=5060 LEN=414
Oct 07 12:30:01 CRON[19318]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Oct 07 12:30:01 CRON[19319]: (www-data) CMD ([ -x /usr/share/awstats/tools/update.sh ] && /usr/share/awstats/tools/update.sh)
Oct 07 12:30:01 CRON[19318]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user www-data
Oct 07 12:30:07 postfix/smtpd[19323]: connect from 246.red-79-148-239.staticip.rima-tde.net[79.148.239.246]
Oct 07 12:30:07 postfix/smtpd[19323]: disconnect from 246.red-79-148-239.staticip.rima-tde.net[79.148.239.246] helo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
```

I tried to enable the wsgi module again, and restart apache2, and that worked. So it seems apache2 cant restart if I disable wsgi.

Comment: Did you remove the configurations you added when you installed iredadmin?

Comment: Perhaps not, do you have an idea of where they are stored?

Comment: How did you install that iresadmin in the first place you will need to revert those changes you made, don't use it so can't really direct you but since you deleted it and from your link, you may need to fix those .

Comment: Yeah alright, thanks though, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Look at disabling `apache module wsgi` since you enabled it to use with iredadmin then I think a `sudo a2dismod wsgi` might help! Does `/home/iredadmin` exist?

Comment: Ok re-enable that module with `sudo a2enmod wsgi ` and restart apache

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I tried to uninstall all packages that was installed on that date, and it fucked up the website for a while. Had to go do some other stuff for some hours, but I did sudo systemctl status apache2.service and it said there was a syntax error in the default-ssl.conf under sites-enabled that iredadmin had changed, fixed the syntax and everything was back to normal.. Still gonna check if it throws error messages in the log though.